# Mac OS X El Capitan - Wi-fi drops when a lot of requests (or high load of processor)

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, osx-el-capitan

This is very annoying issue. I'm noticing it when having multiple requests (slack, telegram, a lot of tabs in chrome, etc.) - wi-fi just drops (all wi-fi networks are not displayed in the dropdown). My system details:

[image]

Comment: So are you telling us that this doesn't happen when you use only one service? What do you mean by "wifi just drops"? Does the wifi icon in the status bar go to no connection? How about other devices on the same network/router?

Comment: other devices work fine, it's only this mac. By "drops" I mean wi-fi becomes off and I cannot turn it on (when clicking it doesn't react).

Comment: What do the logs say? Also, did you try running the wireless diagnostics tool? (option-click the Wi-Fi menu extra to see that option)